# Run rsync in background

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync, server

I need to rsync, this is my command:

```
rsync -aAXvP --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} root@xx.xx.xx:/* /
```

But I need to close ssh connection, so the process should go in background. I tried with nohup and screen, but they exit. How can I run rsync in background?

Comment: Did you try to run it in foreground?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cron to schedule the job to run.  From the command line type crontab -e and add the below line to run today at noon, change the 12 to a 24 hour time for a different time.

The time parameters are in this order: 
minute (0-59), hour (0-23, 0 = midnight), day (1-31), month (1-12), weekday (0-6, 0 = Sunday),

```
crontab -e
##Add this line##
01 12 11 11 * rsync -aAXvP --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} root@xx.xx.xx:/* /
```

Here is info on Cron: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto